# Using an ND array to select on a dimension

Tags: python, numpy

How do I use an ndarray matrix to select elements of an ndarray?

Here's an example of what I mean.

```
a = np.arange(9)
b = np.arange(5)
c = np.arange(12)
A, B, C = np.meshgrid(a, b, c, indexing='ij')
```

Now, for each value of `a`, `c`, I want the `b` that minimizes `A+C=B`. Get the indices:

```
idx = np.abs(A+C-B).argmin(axis=1)
```

Clearly, `idx` has shape `(9, 12)` - it contains the index of b for each of the `9` a, and each of the `12` c.

Now, I would like to select the matrices with the "optimized b". That is, something along the lines of

```
B[:, idx, :]
```

that supposedly has shape `(9, 1, 12)` - because for each of the other combinations, it has only one value of `b` - the minimizing one. Now, `B[:, idx, :]` instead gives me the mesh of all potential combinations with shape `(9, 9, 12, 12)`. I also tried

```
B[np.arange(B.shape[0]), idx, np.arange(B.shape[2])]
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,) (9,12) (12,)
```

*How do I get that specific type of matrix I described above?*

Comment: What are you trying to do? It looks like you make it way too complicated.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I want to project downwards `A, B, C` of shape `9, 5, 12` onto `AA, BB, CC` of shape `(9, 1, 12)`, where I have replaced `b` with `b=b(A, C)`. In the example code above, `b(A, C)` is given by `idx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add an axis there with [`np.newaxis/None`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) to trigger [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
B[np.arange(B.shape[0])[:,None], idx, np.arange(B.shape[2])]
```

The idea basically is to map the rows of `idx` with the first indexing array of `np.arange(B.shape[0])` and as such we need to add an axis there. For mapping the columns of `idx`, we already have `np.arange(B.shape[2])` aligned along the columns of it.

**Alternative to `np.newaxis`**

Another way to add that new axis would be with `reshaping` Thus, we could replace `B[np.arange(B.shape[0])[:,None]` with `np.arange(B.shape[0]).reshape(-1,1)`.

---

**Further optimization**

We could optimize the codes, by using *open arrays* to replace the huge arrays created by `meshgrid`, like so -

```
A0, B0, C0 = np.ix_(a,b,c)
idx = np.abs(A0+C0-B0).argmin(axis=1)
```

Thus, get the final output, like so -

```
B[np.arange(len(a))[:,None], idx, np.arange(len(c))]
```

Just to give ourselves the idea of memory saving here -

```
In [47]: A.nbytes + B.nbytes + C.nbytes
Out[47]: 12960
```

whereas `A0, B0, C0` are views into the input arrays `a, b, c` respectively and as such don't occupy any additional memory, i.e. absolutely free -

```
In [49]: np.shares_memory(a,A0)
Out[49]: True
```

For completeness sake, a direct way to get `idx` would be -

```
np.abs(a[:,None,None]+c-b[:,None]).argmin(axis=1)
```